# SASS: calc() vs normal calculation?

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I previously started working with SASS (scss to be specific) and was wondering, if there's any difference/advantage/disadvantage between the css calc() method or sass calculation?

```
$divide-by: 50;

//CSS calc()
.example1 {
  height: calc(100vw / #{$divide-by});
}

//SASS calculation
.example2 {
  height: 100vw / $divide-by;
}
```

Comment: A calculation in SASS would give you a “static” result only. `calc` allows you to mix units, such as `calc(100vw - 5em)`, that also take the _current_ effective values into account.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SASS calculation is made on compilation. While CSS `calc()` is always made on the browser. 
For example:

SASS `height: 100px / 2;` will compile to `height: 50px;` <- and this is what the browser will see always no matter what.

CSS `width: calc(100% - 20px)` will always be this even on the browser, and at that point the browser will do the calculations depending on what that 100% looks like.

in your case `height: 100vw / $divide-by;` i belive you variable will be considered as a `vw` value, so if `$divide-by` is 20, then the compiles version of that height will be `height: 5vw;`

Let me know if the explanation did not help, and I will try to give you some resources to read.

Comment: if `$divide-by`is 20 then height would become `5vw`

Comment: In other words, if you want to build responsive, then in most cases i should prefere calc() over SASS calculation?

Comment: @Morpheus Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @Tanckom Yes, for reponsive purposes `calc()` is the option. SASS calculations are useless when it comes to responsive because on compilation it is not aware of the size of the window.

Comment: but how to use css calculation with the variables I have on sass?

Comment: @AlanDonizete You can just declare your variables and then do  width: `calc($var1 + $var2)`